# Is dynamically creating and dropping collections in MongoDB going to create scalability issues?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have an application (built in Meteor) that provides some ad hoc reporting capabilities to the end user.  I have built up that functionality by using the aggregation pipeline to produce the results for a given query.  This makes it extremely fast and I was using `$out` to push the results right into a results table.

The results table included a queryID, which the client used to figure out which were the correct results.

Unfortunately, as you may know (and I discovered), that doesn't work so well once you have more than one user running reports at a time because `$out` deletes the whole results table before pushing the new query in.

I see three possible workarounds:

1. Run the aggregation, but manually push the results into the results collection
2. `$out` the results into a temporary collection (dynamically named to avoid conflicts) and then manually copy the results from there into results collection, immediately dropping the temporary one.  This made some sense when I thought I could use `copyTo()`, but that doesn't appear possible within Meteor, so I think this option doesn't make much sense relative to #1 in this case.
3. `$out` the results into a temporary collection (dynamically named to avoid conflicts) and have the client pull its results directly from there.  I would then periodically drop the extra collections after say 24 hours (like I do with specific query results in the main collection today).

#3 would be the fastest by far - the time it takes to manually copy rows dwarfs the time it takes the queries to run.  But I'm concerned about the impact of creating and dropping so many collections.

We're not talking millions of users here, but if an average of 500 users a day were each running 10-20 reports, there could be an additional 5-10k collections in the database at any one time.  That seems like a lot.  Perhaps I could be smarter about cleaning them up somehow, though I can't just immediately remove them because a user might want to have multiple tabs open with different reports.  Even still, we're potentially talking about hundreds to thousands of collections.

Is that going to be a problem?

Are there other approaches I should consider instead?

Other recommendations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping a collection in mongoDB is very efficient operation, anyway much more efficient than deleting some documents in a larger collection.
Maximum number of collections is quite high, only limited by namespace  [namespace](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/) in MMAPv1 while no hard limit exists in wiretiger engine.
So I would favor your solution #3.
Some improvements/alternatives you can think:

1. Consider creating the collections in a separated database (say per day) then you can drop the entire database in a single operation without having to drop individual collections.
2. Use an endpoint for the result set, cash the results then drop the $out collection. Let cache handle user requirements and only rerun the aggregation if cache has expired or something.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of activity is done very easily in relational databases such as mysql or pgsql. You might consider synchronising your data to a separate relational database for the purposes of reporting.

There is a package https://github.com/perak/mysql-shadow which claims to provide synchronisation. I played with it and it didn't work perfectly, although doing just one way sync is more likely to succeed.

The other option is to use Graphql over a mongo/mysql hybrid database which can be done with the Apollo stack http://www.apollodata.com/